# how to hide errors messages generated by HPONCG in powershell output console

Tags: powershell

Below is a line of code writing configuration to HP ILO successfully using powershell script.
`"C:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\HPONCFG\hponcfg.exe" /f $File /l log.txt |Out-Null`
If any configuration which is already available in ILO the HPONCFG writes an error on powershell output console.

Error written by HPONCFG in powershell output console as below:

````
    <!-- Status  = 0x0055-->
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (<!-- Status  = 0x0055-->:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : bjsctinaspa01p

<!-- Message = Duplicate record exists.-->```

How this error can be hide from appearing in output console?
````

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to execute the command with `2>&1`?

```
"C:\Program Files\Hewlett Packard Enterprise\HPONCFG\hponcfg.exe" /f $File /l log.txt 2>&1 | out-null
```

`2>&1` sends standard error to where ever standard output is being redirected which we will make `Out-Null`